# Telnet closes by foreign host during scripts running

Tags: windows, telnet

I telnet to a windows machine from a Linux server to run a python script. The script will keep running about 25mins while it always exits after about 20mins running because the Telnet is closed. It shows "connection closed by foreign host" on Linux server.

Is there any way to keep the session open during the script running?

Telnet configuration on windows:

```
The following are the settings on localhost

Alt Key Mapped to 'CTRL+A'  :   YES
Idle session timeout        :   Not On
Max connections             :   10
Telnet port                 :   23
Max failed login attempts   :   3
End tasks on disconnect     :   YES
Mode of Operation           :   Console
Authentication Mechanism    :   NTLM, Password
Default Domain              :   NGAI_Veriwave
State                       :   Running
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to enable keepalives on your telnet session.  If you are doing it from the Python side, you typically do:

```
x = sock.setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
```

I'm not sure if that works when the Python is the host, though -- you should look to see if your telnet program (e.g. putty) has that option as well.  [Here](https://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Handling_Socket_Error_and_Keepalive) is a bit more information on the topic.

Comment: client = telnetlib.Telnet()
client.open('10.88.177.195')                              client.get_socket().setsockopt( socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)                                                                          I tried this way but seems doesn't work. @Patrick Maupin

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the Telnet service has `IdleSessionTimeout` enabled (`timeoutactive=yes`).

I doubt it has anything at all to do with TCP KeepAlives.

Comment: I've disabled the IdleSessionTimeout.

Comment: Firewalls and even many NAT routers can interrupt "idle" TCP connections too, and to the client this would look like the server closed the connection.  Perhaps that's where the KeepAlives idea comes in though these days most firewalls aren't fooled if configured to be aware of that stunt.  In any case none of this is a programming question.